# How can I get data from ViewModel to Activity or Fragment in clean and simple way?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin-coroutines

I have a question... sometimes, I need to get data from ViewModel directly. For example, Let's say there's a `isChecked()` method in ViewModel. And I want to use it in the if condition.

```
if(viewModel.isChecked()){
    // TODO:
}
```

So, what I am doing right now is:

```
fun isChecked(): Boolean = runBlocking {
    val result = dbRepo.getData()
    val response = apiRepo.check(result)
    return response.isSuccessful
}
```

It uses runBlocking. So, it runs on MainThread. I don't think it's a good way because it can freeze the screen. But yes, if the condition needs to run, it needs to wait it until it gets the data from DB and Network.

Another way that I can think of is using LiveData. However, I can't use it in the condition. So, I needs to move the condition in the observer block. But sometimes, this can't be done because there can be something before the condition. And it doesn't seem to look direct but writing code here and there and finally get that data.

So, Is there any simpler way than this?

Comment: If you want to offload your work from MainThread to the background you can do your work using kotlin-coroutines async-await or withContext.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet if you have something slow or blocking like that is to rethink how you are using the data entirely. Instead of trying to return it, use LiveData or callbacks to handle the response asynchronously without causing your UI to hang or become laggy. In these cases you really only have three options:

1. Use a callback to handle when the response is received
2. Use observable data like LiveData to handle when the response is received
3. Change the method to a suspend function and call it from a coroutine

Forcing a method to wait to return on the main thread without using one of these is **going** to cause the app to hang.

**Callback to get state**

It's hard to say definitely what the best solution for you is without more details about how you are using `isChecked()`, but one pattern that could work would be to use a callback to handle what you were formerly putting in the if statement, like this (in the ViewModel):

```kotlin
fun getCheckedState(callback: (Boolean)->Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        // do long-running task to get checked state,
        // using an appropriate dispatcher if needed
        val result = dbRepo.getData()
        val response = apiRepo.check(result)

        // pass "response.isSuccessful" to the callback, to be
        // used as "isChecked" below
        callback(response.isSuccessful)
    }
}
```

You would call that from the activity or fragment like this:

```kotlin
viewModel.getCheckedState { isChecked ->
  if( isChecked ) {
    // do something
  }
  else {
    // do something else
  }
}

// CAUTION: Do NOT try to use variables you set inside 
// the callback out here!
```

*A word of caution* - the code inside the callback you pass to `getCheckedState` does not run right away. Do not try to use things you set inside there outside the callback scope or you fall into [this common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o/70178210#70178210)

**Simpler Callback**

Alternately, if you only want to run some code when `isChecked` is true, you could simplify the callback like this

```kotlin
fun runIfChecked(callback: ()->Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        // do long-running task to get checked state,
        // using an appropriate dispatcher if needed
        val result = dbRepo.getData()
        val response = apiRepo.check(result)

        // only call the callback when it's true
        if( response.isSuccessful ) {
            callback()
        }
    }
}
```

and call it with

```kotlin
viewModel.runIfChecked {
  // do something
}

// Again, don't try to use things from the callback out here!
```

Comment: Having callback to ViewModel is not a good solution.

Comment: If there is some reason this doesn't work for your case then you need to explain that in your question. Using a blocking return is definitely not a good solution. Using callbacks or observable data *is* the recommend approach for this type of problem

Comment: Your other option would be to load the `isChecked` state once when the activity loads then just use it when needed, but that only works if it is constant, not something that could change based on user input

Answer (score -1):

Use lifecyclescope.launch(Dispatcher.IO) instead of runblocking

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code on your ViewModel class:

```
suspend fun isChecked(): Boolean {
    val response: Response? = null
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result = dbRepo.getData()
        response = apiRepo.check(result)
    }.join()
    return response?.isSuccessful
}
```

From Activity:

```
// Suppose you have a button
findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener({
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        if (viewModel.isChecked()) {
            Log.d("CT", "Do your others staff")
        }
    }
})
```

Hope it work file. If no let me comment

Comment: if it's suspend, I need to use coroutine in Activity.

Comment: @c-an pls try with latest update

Comment: This is not I wanted. I don't want to use coroutine in Activity like that. That's too long.

Comment: @c-an as my best try I updated the code. If you get better solution, pls let me know. thanks